# Awk access to dictionary in gsub

Tags: dictionary, awk, replace

I have the next code and I want to access the position "\1" which matches in the text like (([0-9]+)) in the dictionary d that I create in the `BEGIN` block.
The problem is that in `gensub`, d[["\1"]] prints this literally, instead of the dictionary word.

How could I achieve it?

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  while (getline < "dictionary")
     d["(("i++"))"]=$0
}
{
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
  $i=tolower($i)
}
{
print gensub(/(\(\([0-9]+\)\))/, d["\\1"], "g")
}' fileToReplace.log
```

Example of fileToReplace.log:

```
|||

I want to go to d'((2)) from ((1)

I want to go

To d'(1))

From (4)

|||
```

Example of dictionary:

```
UK
Dublin
Madrid
Ireland
```

And the expected output is:

```
|||

I want to go to d'Dublin from UK

I want to go

To d'UK

From Ireland

|||
```

Basically what I need is to match the number inside any combination of parens and replace this combination (all the parens and the number) with its corresponding position in the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `d["\\1"]` is evaluated before `gensub()` is even called and so before `"\\1"` has any meaning other than that literal string, certainly not a backreference expansion. Look:

```
$ echo 'aBc' | awk '{d["B"]="X"; sub(/B/,d["&"])}1'
ac

$ echo 'aBc' | awk '{d["&"]="X"; sub(/B/,d["&"])}1'
aXc
```

You want something like this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { d[NR]=$0; next }
{
    head = ""
    tail = tolower($0)
    while ( match(tail,/\(+[0-9]+\)+/) ) {
        trgt = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/[()]/,"",trgt)
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) d[trgt]
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head tail
}

$ awk -f tst.awk dictionary fileToReplace.log
|||

i want to go to d'Dublin from UK

i want to go

to d'UK

from Ireland

|||
```

Comment: It work so well! The only problem is that I would like to match the number inside the parenthesis.
Example: from ((158)) get 158, and not all the word. It's because there are in the text words like ((158) and others like ((158))

Comment: I THINK I know what you mean so I've edited my answer. If that's not it then edit your question to include some concise, testable, sample input and expected output.

Comment: You are right! I have edited the publication so now It has an example. Thank you!

Comment: Now it's more confusing since I can't see the correlation between the dictionary order and the numbers in your other file and you have some cases with unmatched parens which idk if they're supposed to match the dictionary values or not - edit your question again to include the expected output given those 2 input files and explain how any of those dictionary entries gets the value `6025`, for example.

Comment: Okay! I think it is better explained now

Comment: I dont understand exactly how match and gsub are working but it works really well, Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Add some `print` statements to print all the variables before/after every statement in the script and you'll see what each step does.